# How to retrieve user register details into web page?

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

Hai i am new to the PHP programming.I was create register page and login page.when user login by using username and password,i want to display the user register detail.I want to know how to retrieve user register details into webpage.

I am using this code for reg and login.

For Register code:

```
 <html>
<title>Register Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm()
{
var a=document.f.name.value;
var b=document.f.pass.value;
var c=document.f.email.value;
var d=document.f.mobile.value;
 var e=document.f.sex.value;

if ((a==null || a=="") && (b==null || b=="") && (c==null || c=="") &&       
    (d==null ||    d==""))
   {
alert("All Field must be filled out");
return false;
}
if (a==null || a=="")
{
alert("Username must be filled out");
return false;
}
if (b==null || b=="")
{
alert("password must be filled out");
return false;
}
if (c==null || c=="")
{
alert("Email must be filled out");
return false;
}
if (d==null || d=="")
{
 alert("Enter the mobile number");
return false;
}
if(e=="Select")
{
alert("Please choose gender");
return false;
}



}
 </script>
 <style>
 #abc
 {
 background-color:#FF3366;
 }
 </style>
 <body bgcolor="#0099CC">
 <h1 id="abc"><center>Welcome to the register page</center></h1>
 <form name="f" action="regdb.php" method="post" onSubmit="return validateForm()">
 <table align="center">
 <tr><td>Fullname :&nbsp;<br><br></td><td><input type="text" name="name" id="name">
 <br><br></td></tr>

 <tr><td>Password :&nbsp;<br><br></td><td><input type="password" name="pass" id="pass">
 <br><br></td></tr> 
 <tr><td>Email    :&nbsp;<br><br></td><td><input type="text" name="email" id="email">
 <br><br></td></tr> 
 <tr><td>Mobile No:&nbsp;<br><br></td><td><input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile">
 <br><br></td></tr>

 <tr><td>Gender      :&nbsp;<br><br></td><td><select name="sex"><option>Select</option>
                                     <option>Male</option>
                                     <option>Female</option></select><br><br></td></tr>
 <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" 
  value="register"></td></tr>                                              
 </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Register_db code:

```
 <?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(!$con)
{
die("could not connect:".mysql_error());
}
 mysql_select_db("manoj",$con);

if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['pass']) && isset($_POST['email']) && 
isset($_POST['mobile']) && isset($_POST['sex']))
{ 
//Prevent SQL injections 
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']); 
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']); 
$mobile = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mobile']);
$sex = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sex']); 

//Get MD5 hash of password 
 $password = $_POST['pass'];
//Check to see if username exists 
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM register WHERE name = '".$username."'");
if (mysql_num_rows($sql)>0) 
{ 
echo "The username you have entered is already exist. Please try another username.";
echo '<a href="reg.php">Try Again</a>';
exit;
} 
mysql_query("INSERT INTO register (name, password, email,mobile,sex) VALUES (    
'$username', '$password', '$email','$mobile','$sex')");
 echo "Thank You for Registration.";
echo '<a href="login.php">Click Here</a> to login you account.';
exit;
} 
?>
```

For Login Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Php Simple Login Form</title>

</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm()
{
var a=document.f.username.value;
var b=document.f.password.value;

if ((a==null || a=="") && (b==null || b==""))
{
alert("All Field must be filled out");
return false;
}
if (a==null || a=="")
{
alert("Username must be filled out");
return false;
}
if (b==null || b=="")
{
alert("password must be filled out");
return false;
}

}
</script>
<style>
#abc
{
    background-color: #EFFBEF;
     text-decoration: blink;
  }
 #def
 {
    background-color:#00BFFF;

 } 

</style>

<body bgcolor="#00BFFF">
<div id="containt" align="center">
<form name="f" action="logindb.php" method="post" onSubmit="return validateForm()">
<center><h1 id="abc">Welcome To My Page </h1></center>
<div id="header"><h2 class="sansserif"> Login Here</h2></div>
<table>

    <tr>
        <td>Enter Username:</td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="username" size="20"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Enter Password:</td>
        <td><input type="password" name="password" size="20"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
         <td><input type="submit" value="Log In"></td>

    </tr>
</table>
<b>Don't have an account,please click here&nbsp;<a href="reg.php">Sign Up</a>  
 </b><br><br> 
 </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

For Login_db Code:

```
<?php

session_start();

$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(!$con)
{
die("could not connect:".mysql_error());
}


 mysql_select_db("manoj",$con);


$username = $_POST["username"]; 
$password = $_POST["password"]; 

$match = "select id from register where name = '".$_POST['username']."' and password = 
 '".$_POST['password']."'";
$qry = mysql_query($match);

$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($qry);

if ($num_rows<=0 ) 
{ 
echo "Incorrect username/password"; 
header('Location: login.php');
}
else 
{ 
//have them logged in 
$_SESSION['user']= $_POST["username"];
header('Location: profile.php');
} 

?>
```

Here i am trying to display the user profile details-profile.php:

```
 <?php
session_start();
echo "You are Welcome ". $_SESSION['user'];
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(!$con)
{
die("could not connect:".mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("manoj",$con);

$sql="select * from register where name = '".$_SESSION['user']."'";
$res=mysql_query($sql);
echo "<table border='0'>";
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($res))
echo"<tr>"."<td>"."Name :"."</td>"."<td>".$r['name']."</td>"."</tr>";
 echo"<tr>"."<td>"."Password :"."</td>"."<td>".$r['password']."</td>"."</tr>";
echo"<tr>"."<td>"."Email :"."</td>"."<td>".$r['email']."</td>"."</tr>";
echo"<tr>"."<td>"."Mobile Number :"."</td>"."<td>".$r['mobile']."</td>"."</tr>";
echo"<tr>"."<td>"."Gender :"."</td>"."<td>".$r['sex']."</td>"."</tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo"<p align='right'><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a></p>";
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

I am using this code to retrieve login user details,but unable to display details,it display username only.Please help me.

Comment: Please tell me you are using indentation in your actual code!?!?

Comment: Please read this tutorial on [readable code](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/top-15-best-practices-for-writing-super-readable-code/).

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the `{ }` delimiters of your `while` loop.

It should be like :

```
echo "<table border='0'>";
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    // echo what you need
}
echo "</table>";
```

Plus, the use of `mysql_*` functions is deprecated, you should consider using `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Comment: +1 good catch. should probably add the mysql_fetch_assoc like I have as well... that's going to be the next error he gets

Comment: @Orangepill according to php.net mysql_fetch_array($res) works with second variable defaulting to MYSQL_BOTH which would give assoc and num.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification... I have removed my answer since it was incorrect.

Comment: @manoj if you want the users to be able to modify their details, you can display a `form` similar to the register one filled with the data from MySQL, and then make an `UPDATE` query to change the table content when this `form` is submitted.